# Why most Christians say Jesus’ resurrection was on a Sunday?

Tags: resurrection, sunday

> John 20:1
>  Now on **the first day of the week** Mary Magdalene came to
> the tomb early, while it was still dark, and saw that the stone had
> been taken away from the tomb.

If in the point of view of Adventist, to me it seems suitable when they say *"Jesus resurrection is on Sunday"*, because in the pov of Adventist - Sunday is the first day of the week.

So, if other Christians say that the first day of the week is Monday, 
then isn't *"the resurrection day is on Monday"* more suitable ?

---

ADDITION:

In simple way :
Q: On what date Jesus resurrected ?
A: 17 Nisan 3793 = 4 April 0033 (from the internet, Gregorian Calendar)

Q: What day is Jesus rose from the death?
A: The first day of the week

My conclusion :
17 Nisan 3793 / 4 April 0033 = The first day of the week

According to the Christian Adventist:
What day is the 7th day of the week to rest? (Sabbath)
What day is the first day of the week?
What day Jesus die ? What day Jesus resurrection day ?

According to the Non-Adventist Christian:
What day is the 7th day of the week to rest? (Sabbath)
What day is the first day of the week?
What day Jesus die ? What day Jesus resurrection day ?

Comment: For Jews, by whom both Testaments were written, Sunday is the first day of the week. Also, in Eastern Christianity, Sunday is still the first day of the liturgical week. (That the secular reckoning differs is besides the point).

Comment: Why do you think any Christian denomination thinks the first day of the week is Monday? That seems like an exotic enough claim to require sourcing.

Comment: @Lucan, thank you for your respond. So, in the point of view of Jewish Christian and the Adventist, (to me) they are correct when they say "Jesus resurrection day is Sunday", because they holds : _"Sunday is the first day of the week"_ as you wrote. So, why the other Christians who holds : _"Sunday is the seventh day of the week"_ not say that "Jesus resurrection day is Monday" ?

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil, because I thought that in the pov of other Christians, the command to rest on the seventh day is Sunday.

Comment: Sunday is the first day of the week, not Monday. Monday is sometimes referred to as the first day of the work week: Monday - Friday.

Comment: @KenGraham, so it's "correct" if the Adventist say "_The resurrection day is Sunday_", the first day of the week. Consequently in the pov Adventist, the seventh day of the week is the day of rest, which is Saturday.

Comment: @kutschkem, thank you for the link. Now I'm a bit understand of it. So, _"the non-Adventist Christian change that the day of rest from the seventh day of the week, to the first day of the week"_ . Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I will upvote this question if you remove the claim that some Christians call Monday the first day of the week or give a good source for it. My understanding is that that usage (which I believe is official in Germany) was introduced for commercial reasons and deliberately detracts from the significance of Christianity. I believe the "Monday is the first day" idea is the source of your confusion.

Comment: @BitChaser, sorry - I don't have any source. It's just by my own logic : IF Christian say _"the 7th day of the week (Sabbath) to rest is Sunday"_ THEN (me) to this Christian, the 1st day of the week is Monday.

Comment: Sorry, if you can't explain or justify what misled you to think Monday makes sense, then I have to downvote. The question can only be answered as a frame challenge, and the answerer has to speculate why you misunderstood.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between Adventists and other Christians is NOT which day is the seventh or not. It is whether the christian Sabbath should be on the seventh day (the day of the jewish Sabbath, the day that was set as sabbath in the OT) or on the first day (the day Jesus was resurrected), changing the day of the sabbath. Note that the NT says the disciples gathered on the first day of the week, so it doesn't come out of nowhere that Sunday is the day that is now used by most christians as the sabbath.

So everyone agrees as to what day of the week Jesus was resurrected, that is not the point of dispute at all.

Comment: Kutschkem, thank you for the answer. You wrote :_It is whether the christian Sabbath should be on the seventh day or on the first day_. Sorry I don't understand that, because to me the beginning point is "what day is the command : [rest on the seventh day] ?".

Comment: @karma The OT command is rest on the seventh day -> saturday. In the NT, the saints met at the first day to commemorate the resurrection -> sunday. So, christians today still rest every seven days, but on the first instead of the seventh, to commemorate the resurrection. Clear enough?

Comment: Kutschkem, so am I correct to say : the non-Adventist Christian actually admit that the biblical seventh day of the week is Saturday ? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @karma Yes, you are correct; most churches use the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Some Seventh Day Adventists believe Jesus was resurrected on a Saturday. For them, Jesus was crucified on Wednesday and the Last Supper was on Tuesday. That allows time for Jesus to be three whole days in the tomb. They consider Passover to add a second sabbath during the week.

Comment: "*everyone agrees as to what day of the week Jesus was resurrected*" — Not quite. They agree that the tomb was found empty on Sunday morning, the first day of the week. The resurrection itself could have happened just before sunset on Saturday, exactly three days and three nights after a Wednesday crucifixion. — For scriptural harmony, see this chart: [Crucifixion/Resurrection Synoptic Time Table](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Tables/crucifixion-resurrection/).

Comment: @RayButterworth Ok, enlighten me: Which group believes in a wednesday crucifixion? In that case, just read "everyone" as "mostly everyone".

Comment: @kutschkem, in addition to some SDAs here are a few examples: [Chronology of the Crucifixion | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/jesus-christ-the-real-story/the-chronology-of-the-crucifixion-and-resurrection), [Easter | Living Church of God](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/easter-the-untold-story/content), [Crucified and Resurrected? | Philadelphia Church of God](https://www.thetrumpet.com/6972-when-was-christ-crucified-and-resurrected), [Not On Friday - Herman L Hoeh](https://www.hwalibrary.com/cgi-bin/get/hwa.cgi?action=getbklet&InfoID=1327166100)

Answer (score 2):

> So, if other Christians say that the first day of the week is Monday ...

Indeed, in many countries (for example here in Germany) the week starts with Monday and ends with Sunday.

However, in Jewish culture the week always started with Sunday and ended with Saturday. (More precisely: The sunset between Saturday to Sunday.)

> Why most Christian say Jesus resurrection is on Sunday?

Monday makes absolutely no sense:

The three women prepared the dead body of Jesus for the funeral with expensive oil and interrupted their activities because of the Jewish holiday, which is the Saturday.

They wanted to continue the funeral preparations after the Jewish holiday, which means: After the Saturday.

It makes no sense that these women waited another extra day, so they surely planned to continue Sunday in the morning.

And the Bible tells us that Jesus was already alive when they tried to continue the preparations.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** The Hebrew word translitterated "Sabbath" means "time of rest". It does not mean "seventh day". In Genesis, it says God rested (Sabbath) on the seventh day (our Saturday). Some Christians (not just Adventists) continue the Jewish practice of resting (Sabbath) on the seventh day. Most Christians choose their primary day of worship to be Sunday, the first day of the week, because Jesus was resurrected on "the first day of the week".

Some Christians now say Sunday, the first day of the week, is their "day of rest" (Sabbath). They may apply some, but not all, of the Jewish rules about no work on the Sabbath to Sunday. Other Christians prefer to call the seventh day, Saturday, the Sabbath but say we no longer keep it as a day of rest, because we have entered into a perpetual time of rest.

The modern practice of calling Monday the "first day of the week" didn't exist until a few decades ago. Saturday has always been the seventh day and Sunday the first.